# Problem when casting in C

Tags: c, unix, casting

I have the following data structure in C:

```
typedef struct {
    void* buffer;
        ...
} SharedMemory;
```

I have defined a sharedMemoryBuffer that will contain an array of SharedMemory structs:

```
sharedMemoryBuffer = createSharedMemory("/xxxyz", NUM_BLOCKS * sizeof(Block));
```

my problem is now in trying to read from the shared memory a block in a given position. I thought the following should be enough, but the C compiler is complaining:

```
Block* block = (Block*)sharedMemoryBuffer->buffer[readPosition];
```

The error is:

```
Invalid use of void expression.
```

How should I cast the last line of code such that the compiler doesn't yell at me about that line?

Thanks

Comment: Based on the lines you've provided, it sounds like `void *buffer;` should actually be `Block *buffer;` here.

Comment: Yes it should. Problem is that I designed this structure so that it could be used in other situations. Is there another way to code in C such that I can use my SharedMemory structure with several types? char*'s, int*'s, etc? Something like generics in C#?

Comment: Not really. This is good enough for most situations. If you had C++ you could use templates but I don't want to be the "If you had C++ you could..." guy. This is good enough for most competent C programmers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sharedMemoryBuffer->buffer` is of type `void *`. That means you do not know what type it points to, so you can't  dereference it (with either `*` or `[]`).

If it's actually the `buffer` you want to cast, you should look into:

```
Block* block = ((Block*)(sharedMemoryBuffer->buffer))[readPosition];
```

or, more likely:

```
Block* block = &(((Block*)(sharedMemoryBuffer->buffer))[readPosition]);
```

since you're trying to get a *pointer* to the desired array element.

Comment: Hmm. I am now getting a "incompatible types when initializing type ‘struct Block *’ using type ‘Block’ error.

Comment: No, the OP's code is equivalent to `(Block *)(sharedMemoryBuffer->buffer[readPosition])` because both `->` and `[]` bind tigter than a cast.

Comment: @devoured, that's because the act of indexing an `X` pointer gives you an `X`. If you want a pointer to the element indexed by `readPosition`, see my update.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is operator precedence: the index operator (`[]`) has higher precedence than the cast, so it tries to take the index of a `void *` and cast it to a `Block *` rather than casting the `void *` to a `Block *` and *then* indexing it. Use parenthesis:

```
Block *block = &((Block *)sharedMemoryBuffer->buffer)[readPosition];
```

or (the way I prefer with pointer arithmetic):

```
Block *block = (Block *)sharedMemoryBuffer->buffer + readPosition;
```

or, if you wanted to copy the `Block` to a stack variable for some reason:

```
Block block = ((Block *)sharedMemoryBuffer->buffer)[readPosition];
```

EDIT: corrected an error. My code produced a `Block` instead of a `Block *` as the OP needed.

Comment: I thought about the paranthesis, and tried in all the possibles ways. It seems that it was in all possible ways but the one you have shown :(

Comment: But now that I think of it, I don't get it. Shouldn't I first try to "find" the item in the array and only after do the cast?

Comment: @devoured - No. You can't index a `void *` pointer. You have to cast it to the item type first. Is this an array of `Block`s or an array of pointers to `Block`s?

Comment: sharedMemoryBuffer->buffer IS an array of blocks.

Comment: @devoured - Then you have to cast the buffer from a `void *` to a `Block *` and then index it, which is what my example does.

Comment: Actually, it's what the example does _now_. I had made a rather grievous error.

Answer (score 2):

Buffer is a void pointer. You can't index into a void pointer.

unsigned char might work better since that's defined as a single byte.

Comment: But then he'll have to manually index by `sizeof(Block)`. Better to cast the buffer to `Block *`, _then_ index it. Also, it's always better to use `void *` where untyped data is called for. `unsigned char *` for random storage is unintuitive.

Answer (score 2):

lets break it down by parenthesizing it as the compiler sees it

```
Block* block = (Block*)(sharedMemoryBuffer->buffer[readPosition]);
```

You'll notice there that you are casting to Block* *after using subscripts to dereference a void pointer* which means you are trying to cast a `void` to `Block*`

What you probably want to do is:

```
Block* block = ((Block*)(sharedMemoryBuffer->buffer))+readPosition;
```

which will point you at the `readPosition`th Block in the buffer

Answer (score 1):

You can not deference a void pointer. You need to cast void pointer to char* then add readposition to it and then cast back to Block*.